# What is the best way to indent text in a DIV when it wraps?

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

So I have a DIV that contains some dynamic text.  Let's say I know the text and font-size but I don't know the size of the DIV.  I'd like the display of the text in the DIV to be intelligent enough to show indentation when text wraps.

Say my original text looked something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing 
elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt
```

Instead, I want it to look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consectetur adipisicing 
   elit, sed do eiusmod 
   tempor incididunt
```

What's the best way to do this if I don't know the size of the DIV a priori?  And what's the best way to do it if I do know the size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 70):

If I understand what you're asking for, this works for me:

```css
div {
    padding-left: 2em;
    text-indent: -2em;
}
```

Comment: I also had to add   "display: inline-block;"   for this to work for me.

Comment: This indents all text after first line, including if you use a `<br>`.  It's not exactly as described for "wrapped text", though convention for a `shift+ent` is to keep left alignment with the previous line, of which `<br>` is the html version, so this should be expected. However, if you're looking for *wrapped text* indentation only, it's not this.

Answer (score 5):

W3C says you just have to use text-indent property.

[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-indent)

```css
.indentedtext
{
    text-align: start;
    text-indent: 5em;
}
```

Comment: W3Schools say it works since IE4 source : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp
Some site on the web suggest to make text-indent correctly tho in IE6 you need to apply it with text-align:left; and display:block;

Answer (score 2):

This should work equally well for both variable and fixed size DIVs.

```
<div style="width: 150px; text-indent: -2em; padding-left: 2em;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt.
</div>
```

Comment: I've tested the code on Firefox 3 and IE7 and it seems to render perfectly well on both.

Answer (score 1):

### Code

For this to work, just add the following code in your CSS file.

```css
div {
  padding-left: 2em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Stack Overflow is a great place for 
  developers of all levels to come
  together and help each other - as
  well as other people - to solve a question!
</div>
```

---

### Explanation

`padding-left` will add some padding to the left size to indent it.

`text-indent` defines the indentation of the first line's indentation, so by setting the value to `-2`, we are overriding the value of `padding-left` (as *2 - -2 = 0*). So, in short, `text-indent` reverses the padding size back to `0`.

`display` will just check the way it looks. For more information about this, see [`display` on *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `text-indent` property:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 45px;
}  

.box p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-indent: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repellendus natus minima ex possimus? Pariatur odit distinctio, similique, adipisci nesciunt molestias iusto ipsa repellendus recusandae unde, enim veniam voluptatem expedita.</p>
</div>
```