# CSS div positioning relative to other divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am creating a timeline feed where there are two items: A icon and some text. Both the icon and the text are enclosed in another div. My goal is to set it up so that when I write a sentence that ends up wrapping around, to just go under the writing and not the actual icon, so it will be neat and organized.

Here is the code:

```
  <div id="right_column" class="large-3 columns">
  <h2>Saved Content</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content_item">
        <div class="content_icon"><i class="ss-icon">doc</i></div>
        <div class="content_text">How to Retain Good Employees</div><br>
      </div>
    <div class="content_item">
      <div class="content_icon"><i class="ss-icon">video</i></div>
      <div class="content_text">Do I really Need a Team? Ask these 6 questions</div><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the css:

```
.content_item {
  color: blue;
 }

.content_item div {
  display: inline;
 }
```

This is the result I am getting, but I don't want the word 'questions' to be under the icon, just the writing.
[image]

Comment: Please post your complete `HTML` and `CSS`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to indent text in a DIV when it wraps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480567/what-is-the-best-way-to-indent-text-in-a-div-when-it-wraps)

Comment: Complete code would rule. But are you speaking to having the icon on their own line? if so, just remove that display: inline on .content_item div

Comment: @evan no I want the icon and text on the same line, but if the line wraps around I only want it under the text not the icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
.content_item div {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

and

```
.content_text{
  float: right; /* or left */
  width: 80%; /* set yout text container width*/
}
```

if it's not work post a screenshot of your previous post result and i can help you quickly

Answer (score 1):

**Try this CSS:**

```
.content_item {
 color: blue;
 display:block;
 }

.content_icon
{
  display: inline-block;
  width:20%;
}

.content_text
{
 display: inline-block;
 width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be after the white space css property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

So:

```
.content_text { white-space: nowrap; }
```